# Meta logo on Main

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've restarted Firefox, so it shouldn't be a matter of the browser getting confused. It appears the Meta sprites are being used on Main:

[image: Christianity masthead]

The main logo is the wrong colour — grey instead of blue — and there is the hint of the "m" from "meta".

I can't tell whether the voting buttons and accept ticks are wrong, but as everything is in the same sprite file, I guess they are.

Comment: Confirmed, I started seeing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks; [my report of this](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5806/21576) hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh: sorry; I hadn't noticed your answer there. I find it's best to raise bugs separately.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, that's probably best; it's unclear if this issue is related to the site upgrade or not.

Comment: @Pawel Could you write an answer rather than edit the question to comment on it, please? Editing an answer into a question is a reason to reject an edit. Thanks. (It also allows me to accept the answer when it's implemented.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach sure.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't roll back an edit containing a pink tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This has been fixed and will be live after next production build.